# AngularJS Material Clickable Tooltip

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-material

I have been searching on internet quite a while, but i can't find any resource that discusses AngularJs Material clickable tooltip.

I need to create a tooltip that later on provides the details of the hovered items, and then let it to be clickable. Once the user clicks the item in the tooltip, it will run another function.

Or can I achieve it using Angular UI Bootstrap? thank you

Can somebody help me? Thank you.

```
 <tr ng-repeat="item in data">
                <td>
                        {{item.name}}

                </td>
                <td>
                        {{item.address}}

                </td>
                <td>
                        {{item.contact}}
                        <md-tooltip md-visible="demo.showTooltip">
                                Data bla bla bla 
                        </md-tooltip>
                </td>
 </tr>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use toggle from material and then customize it as per your use.